# React Memo still rerenders on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am wondering why the console.log({ routes }) is outputting on a search useState update without the search having filtered the data. I have memoized and useCallbacked things.

```js
import { memo, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react'

import * as stations from './stations.json'
import './App.css';

const StyledContainer = {
  "cursor": "pointer",
  "display": "flex",
  "flex-direction": "row"
}

const StyledSegment = {
  "justify-content": "space-between",
  "text-align": "left",
  "width": "33.3%"
}

const baseUrl = 'https://api.wheresthefuckingtrain.com/by-id'

const StationComponent = (fetchSchedule, s) => {
  const { id, location, name, routes = false, stops } = s

  console.log({ routes }) // THIS RERENDERS

  return (
    <div key={id} onClick={() => { fetchSchedule(id) }}>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <h4>{location}</h4>
      {routes && routes.N.length > 0 && <div><label>North</label><ul>{routes.N.map(({ route, time }, idx) => <li key={idx}>Route: {route}<br></br>{new Date(time).toLocaleTimeString()}</li>)}</ul></div>}
      {routes && routes.N.length > 0 && <div><label>South</label><ul>{routes.S.map(({ route, time }, idx) => <li key={idx}>Route: {route}<br></br>{new Date(time).toLocaleTimeString()}</li>)}</ul></div>}
    </div>
  )
}

const MemoizedStationComponent = memo(StationComponent)

function App() {
  const [filteredStationData, setFilteredStationData] = useState(stations)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState() // station name
  const [stationData, setStationData] = useState(stations)

  console.log({stations})

  const fetchSchedule = useCallback(async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, { method: 'get' })
    const json = await res.json()

    console.log("apiCall")

    const copyStationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stations))
    copyStationData[id].routes = json.data[0]

    setStationData(copyStationData)
  })

  const filterStations = useCallback(() => {
    const filteredStations = Object.values(stationData).filter((s) => s.name.includes(search))
    setFilteredStationData(filteredStations)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App" style={StyledContainer}>
      <header className="App-header">
        <input placeholder="Name" onChange={(e) => { setSearch(e.target.value) }} /><button onClick={() => { filterStations() }}>Search</button>
        <div style={StyledSegment}>
          {Object.values(filteredStationData).map(s => <MemoizedStationComponent fetchSchedule={fetchSchedule} s={s} />)}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should also keep in mind that the `memo` HOC docs say "This method only exists as a **[performance optimization](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html)**. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs." Think of it more like a *hint* to React that a component doesn't *need* to rerender, but be aware that React will rerender what it needs to when it needs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add dependencies for useCallback to prevent unnecessary re-renders of your station component.

```js
const fetchSchedule = useCallback(async (id) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, { method: 'get' })
  const json = await res.json()

  console.log("apiCall")

  const copyStationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stations))
  copyStationData[id].routes = json.data[0]

  setStationData(copyStationData)
}, [stations])

const filterStations = useCallback(() => {
  const filteredStations = Object.values(stationData).filter((s) => s.name.includes(search))
  setFilteredStationData(filteredStations)
}, [search])
```

Now each time your stations or search value is changed. Your component will re-render.

Answer (score 3):

Few points:

- You haven't provided [dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to `useCallback`.

> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will
> return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of
> the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to
> optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent
> unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

- Also I notice you haven't passed [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) here: `<MemoizedStationComponent fetchSchedule={fetchSchedule} s={s} />`
  ; this can become problematic (you should have received warning), and you can end up in corrupt state etc., if the elements of the array which you are mapping can reorder for example.
- And general note, if you pass an *object* as prop to memoized component, make sure it is not recreated on each render, or it will break memoization.

Comment: Hi Giorgi, thanks for this it was insightful. I've upvoted your response. First I am wondering what if I pass in the key on the inside of the component in the function declaration as s.id? Secondly, I do a lot of quick passing of props through spreading {...{prop1, prop2}} would spreading make it be recreated?

Comment: @MichaelPaccione refer to the link about keys in the answer it should answer all your questions how to use it. About props what I mean if you do something like this: `<Component someProp={{name:"Nick"}}/>` this would be one example of where a new object is passed each time to the component; because you can think of each re render as the component function being reinvoked, so above code would be same as recreating that object each time.

Comment: Gotcha, okay makes sense on the new object bit. Sounds like best to keep that in local state to avoid troubles.